# CodeIgniter sending complete select instead of single option element from form

Tags: codeigniter, select

This is my function under the model..

```
    public function get_categories_select() {
    // output
    $output = "";

    // query
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("categories");
    $query = $this->db->get();

    // zero result(s)
    if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
        return $output = "No Results Found";
    }

    // result(s)
    $output .= "<select name=\"category\">";
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $output .= "<option value=\"{$row['name']}\">{$row['name']}</option>\n";
    }
    $output .= "</select>";

    // return
    return $output;
}
```

This is my controller..

```
public function add_cellphone() {
    // loading
    $this->load->model("category_model");
    $this->load->model("brand_model");
    // controlling
    $data['categories'] = $this->category_model->get_categories_select();
    $data['brands']     = $this->brand_model->get_brands_select("cell phones");
    if ($this->validate_cellphone() === FALSE) {
        // on failure
        $to_view = "add_cellphone";
    } else {
        // on success
        $data['category'] = set_value('category');
        $data['brand']    = set_value('brand');
        $data['model']    = set_value("model");
        $data['price']    = set_value("price");

        $this->load->model("product_model");
        $this->product_model->add_product($data);
        $to_view = "add_cellphone_success";
    }
    // viewing
    $this->load->view("admin/templates/header");
    $this->load->view("admin/pages/{$to_view}", $data);
    $this->load->view("admin/templates/footer");
}

public function validate_cellphone() {
    // laoding
    $this->load->helper("form");
    $this->load->library("form_validation");
    // validation rules
    $config = array(
            array(
                "field" => "category",  
                "label" => "Category",  
                "rules" => "required",  
            ),
            array(
                "field" => "brand", 
                "label" => "Brand", 
                "rules" => "required",  
            ),
            array(
                "field" => "model", 
                "label" => "Model", 
                "rules" => "required",  
            ),
            array(
                "field" => "price", 
                "label" => "Price", 
                "rules" => "required",  
            ),
            array(
                "field" => "released",  
                "label" => "Released",  
                "rules" => "required",  
            ),
            array(
                "field" => "status",    
                "label" => "Status",    
                "rules" => "required",  
            )
        );
    // controlling
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="error">', '</span>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        return TRUE;
    }
    // no viewing
}
```

Here `$data['cartegory'] and $data['brand']` contains the complete select element with children option element instead of only the option element which is selected from form view. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the form passing validation?

Comment: `set_value` should only be used in your view, to set the `value=""` attribute of `<input>` fields. As fembb says in his answer, you need to use `$this->input->post('category');` to get the post data from the form in your controller.